# Newline charecter not working in log4net for html appender

Tags: log4net

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="E:\ErrorLogs.html" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

the above code newline char works fine with .txt file but not working with .html file

Answer (score 0):

For me, the newline characters that worked are slighly different:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;--------------&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <param name="Footer" value="&#xD;&#xA;--------------&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p - %m%newline" />
</layout>
```

I.e. for the "ConversionPattern" there was `%newline` that worked, for the "Header" and "Footer" there was `&#xD;&#xA;` that worked.

Maybe you can give this a try, too?

Comment: This code is not working ... new line is still not added to HTML Log

Comment: @Pallabi I do not unterstand why you refer to "HTML". The FileAppender usually is for plain text files. If you want some HTML new lines, you _could_ try using `<br />`.

Comment: Exactly Where is need to add the <br /> tag in these line of code: <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[End]" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %m%n " />
      </layout>

Comment: Where to add the <br /> tg in the config File